# Converting the returned urlopen() into a float

Tags: python

Trying to get this to work, but keep on getting "ValueError: could not convert string to float:" error. I've tried read() and readline() but can't figure it out.

Thanks for the help!

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
current_time = urlopen("http://just-the-time.appspot.com/?f=%t")
print current_time.readline()

future = float(current_time.readline()) + 30
print "future" + future
```

Comment: It looks like that URL returns a newline

Comment: What is `print current_time.readline()` outputting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first call to `current_time.readline()` is eating the entire response. The second call to it returns just an empty string. Write that like:

```
now = current_time.readline()
future = float(now) + 30
```

Answer (score 2):

You *already* read the value on the line before. Read it just *once*:

```
current_time = urlopen("http://just-the-time.appspot.com/?f=%t")
current_time = current_time.read()

future = float(current_time) + 30
```